# is this how i check a file extension in a specifc text file?

Tags: c++, string, file-extension

Hello I'm trying to implement a way too check a file extension in a specific text file the code below doesn't seem to do what I want but I was wondering if this is somewhat the right direction to take in doing this. if not what library are there that would allow me to do this in as less code as possible.

```
string fn = ".txt";
if(fn.substr(fn.find_last_of(".") + 1) == ".txt") {
    fprintf(stderr,"yes");
} else {
    fprintf(stderr,"no");
}
```

im on windows 7 32bit

Comment: You tagged this with cout and cin but then use `fprintf` to standard error.  FYI there is an iostream class for standard error, so you can do `cerr << "yes";` and `cerr << "no";`

Comment: By the way, you don't check the file extension "in a file" but "of/in a filename".

Comment: Programatically accessing file extensions is generally a misuse of the filename. A user should be able to put whatever they want as a filename, e.g. notes.txt.old, and that will prevent your program from working. Tell your OS vendor to stop abusing file names this way and to start storing file type metadata in a sane way.

Answer (score 2):

My preferred solution would be `boost::filesystem`, as minus suggests,
but if not:

```
static std::string const targetExtension( ".txt" );
if ( filename.size() >= targetExtension.size()
        && std::equal( filename.end() - targetExtension.size(),
                       filename.end(),
                       targetExtension.begin() ) ) {
    std::cerr << "yes";
} else {
    std::cerr << "no";
}
```

This would seem the simplest to me.

Answer (score 1):

`fn.substr(fn.find_last_of(".") + 1)` returns `"txt"` without the dot. So either remove `+1` from `substr` or compare with `"txt"` without the dot.

Comment: I'd recommend just "txt".  It's faster, and you've already compared the dot.

Comment: ...but beware that `find_last_of()` will return `npos` if the filename doesn't contain any dots, and as npos is defined as the constant -1 then this code will add one to it and call `substr(0)`.  Thus as written, the "extension" of a string with no dots will be the entire filename...for reasons that do not seem intentionally expressed by this code.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need this to work on Windows, the best solution is to use the Win32 API [PathMatchSpec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773727(v=vs.85).aspx).

For your example:

```
string fn = ".txt";
if(PathMatchSpecA(fn.c_str(), "*.txt") {
    fprintf(stderr,"yes");
} else {
    fprintf(stderr,"no");
}
```

Or as a function:

```
BOOL HasTxtFileExtension(LPCSTR filename)
{
    return PathMatchSpecA(filename, "*.txt");
}
```

As would be expected, this function is case-insensitive and correctly handles the case where the directory contains dots but the file does not, e.g. `C:\\directory.with.dots\\testtxt`.

Answer (score 0):

I think boost filesystem library should help you (extension path function).

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/index.html

Comment: i couldn't get boost libary to work when i tried mainly because its all source and me and building source dont get on :( if someone has pre built binarys for mingw im sold tho

Comment: you can follow this guide http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/more/getting_started/windows.html but its not guaranteed to work with mingw see the beginning